# What is the mood of {יהיו} in Psalm 19:15

Tags: hebrew, psalms, grammar

- יהיו לרצון

  - they shall be of desiring/liking
- אםרי פי

  - speech of my mouth
- והגיון לבי

  - and reasoning/logic of my heart
- לפניך יי צורי וגאלי

  - before you Hashem my rock and my redeemer.

What is the mood of {יהיו} here?

Let me exemplify what I mean by "mood". The following are merely examples of "mood" and not implied as possible answers:

1. I am affirming (speech of my mouth and reasoning of my heart) shall be to your liking. I will make sure. I will put in extreme effort to ensure.
2. I am hoping (speech of my mouth and reasoning of my heart) may be to your liking. I am satisfied with their current state and there is nothing further I can or shall do, so I hope they will be pleasing to you.
3. I am affirming (speech of my mouth and reasoning of my heart) shall be to your liking. I will make sure. I will put in extreme effort to ensure. But I still have no assurance they will be good enuf. Therefore, I still hope they will be too your liking.
4. (speech of my mouth and reasoning of my heart) shall have to be to your liking. Woe unto me if they will not be.
5. Or any other possible moods.

Background work:

- I have checked up all the occurrences of {יהי / יהיו}. Many/most of the cases are affirmative mood.
- I am aware there is the concept known as "context". If you quote "context", please include in answer why your "context" is applicable and not willy-nilly concocted.

Comment: Note 19:15 is Jewish/Masoret enumeration. Christian enumeration may be different.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a sensible question. I believe you are asking whether the verb is basically declarative (“they will be”) or jussive (“may they be”).  Unfortunately, the answer is that this verb doesn't have different forms for those two moods, so we have to decide how to read/translate it based on... context!

In this context, since the Lord's reception of the prayer is really up to the Lord and not to the psalmist, I believe it's sensible to read it, “May they be”. Just as one might say politely in English, “I hope it won't be taken amiss if I say...” etc.

Comment: Consider יהי as in יהי רצון or תהי. You can conjugate היה in the declarative and in the jussive and then compare the two conjugations to see which cases are the same. For each case where they are the same, see if there is an example verse in the OT and show how we know what the voice of the verb. If you can write a really complete answer, the OP will get up-votes.

Comment: I can't produce an example to show that two verb forms are identical. Are you aware of distinct declarative and jussive forms of היה?

Comment: I have irrevocable Bible Fundamentalist  proof, that by reading the original text which is the Hebrew masoret text alone, that the Greek scriptures from which you derive your "Lord"  has too many foreign and unfamiliar ideas rejected by the Hebrew text of the Bible and therefore your Greek scriptures cannot and must NOT be used as aid to interpret or comprehend the Hebrew text of the Bible.